# Silverlight as a downlevel WinRT platform

Tags: silverlight, components, themes, windows-8, windows-runtime

Two interrelated questions:

1. For an app suite with an app for each major device platform (iOS, Android, Windows Phone 7, and WinRT), is Silverlight a good platform for a "downlevel" (Mac/7/Vista/XP) version of the WinRT app?
2. If so (or to make it so), what Silverlight components emulate the [Metro controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx#ui_controls) and their themes to minimize the effort of making the Silverlight app consistent with the WinRT app?

Comment: This is extremely difficult to answer because most of the issues you will have when making the application portable the way you are thinking of will not be related to the UI/controls.

It will be the logic in the application that integrates with the platform that will cost quite some effort.

At the same time it will probably very awkward to reproduce a Metro App UI in Silverlight because things that are normal in a Metro App are not so normal on other platforms.

Comment: I agrea with @Erno. In addition, creating one xaml layout to use on a Phone and on a PC just doesn't make sense. The screen dimensions, and the platform conventions are just to different. You might be able to reuse some code for the viewmodels and even more for the models underneath, but you probably want to redesign the screen between phones and PC's.

Comment: @Kris: My question doesn't relate to phone/PC code reuse, but only PC/PC (or PC/tablet) code reuse. The idea is that if you've invested in the UI for a WinRT app (minimum 1024x768 resolution), is there a way to get coverage for Mac/Win7/Vista/XP for small additional effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  Silverlight does not give you the kind of touch support you need to truly match with a Metro style app.  You can use things like [NESL](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nesl/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5519) or roll your own gesture library, but it can never really match the type of experience you will get from a Metro style apps and of course stops being cross platform at that point.  The closest I've ever come is building a Silverlight full-screen out of the browser app where we rolled our own gesture library and it was still unsatisfying.

Metro is a new and unique design language and without an OS that has been built from the ground up to support the experience, you will find it a bad experience and worse, you will be battling the technology the whole way.

Responding to comment: It absolutely can be done.  See http://www.flickr.com/windows7 for example.

Comment: Good point about the fine points of touch. Suppose you took touch off the table. After all, most downlevel clients won't have touch anyway, and the Metro UI is supposed to work just fine with keyboard and mouse. For the sake of consistency and only having to work on the graphical details of a great UI once, what are the value and practicality of using a single Metro design across WinRT and Silverlight?